# Can Perl POD represent quoting from an email?

Tags: perl, documentation

I would like to quote someone in a [Perl POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod) so it looks something like this:

---

Joe said:

> It is a great day to play in the rain!

---

Indenting makes it think it is code so metacpan.org highlights it as code.  I've looked around and not found an example of this, so perhaps it is not supported?  This is the link containing [the quotation](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDL::Opt::Simplex::Simple#Antenna-Geometry:-Use-an-array-for-the-ssize-parameter-from-coarse-to-fine-perturbation) and (if possible) I would like to see the content as a quotation instead of as code.

Ideas?

Comment: Maybe in a `=format html` block with appropriate tags?

Comment: 1) Why do you say "_quoting from an email_" -- how does email matter?  2) So you want some text to appear quoted under pod (just indented really?) ... but you want the pod that you write to appear as desired on metacpan.org?  If that's correct, then do you know how metacpan.org processes pod? (I used their stylesheet for my html docs but that's probably not the whole story.)

Comment: @zdim, sure, I can just indent, but I was asking if there is an existing POD format indended for quoted text (whether from email or another source)

Comment: Right, I got the question once I looked at the link and the source for it.  The problem is that they pass the pod through an HTML formatter and that changes things. (Why is your indentation results in code highlights? It shouldn't?)  I don't know which formatter they use, either.  Looking around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure Pod doesn't have a quote feature.

If you want something that Pod doesn't do, you can make your own translator that recognizes your new feature:

```
=begin quote

It is a great day to play in the rain!

=end quote
```

See [Pod::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Simple) as a good place to start.